# Generate random values in C#

Tags: c#, random, long-integer, int64

How can I generate random Int64 and UInt64 values using the `Random` class in C#?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This should do the trick. (It's an extension method so that you can call it just as you call the normal `Next` or `NextDouble` methods on a `Random` object).

```
public static Int64 NextInt64(this Random rnd)
{
    var buffer = new byte[sizeof(Int64)];
    rnd.NextBytes(buffer);
    return BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
}
```

Just replace `Int64` with `UInt64` everywhere if you want unsigned integers instead and all should work fine.

**Note:** Since no context was provided regarding security or the desired randomness of the generated numbers (in fact the OP specifically mentioned the `Random` class), my example simply deals with the `Random` class, which is the preferred solution when randomness (often quantified as [information entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_entropy)) is not an issue. As a matter of interest, see the other answers that mention `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` (the RNG provided in the `System.Security` namespace), which can be used almost identically.

Comment: +1 for giving the OP what they asked for as well as mentioning the limitations of using Random and offering an alternative if the limitations of Random are too restrictive for the intended use.

Comment: Note that this approach also returns negative numbers and Int64.MaxValue, while System.Random.Next() is constrained to positive numbers including 0 but without Int32.MaxValue.

Comment: @Christoph: Yeah, well observed. You could however modify my method quite easily to only produce positive values by ignoring the MSB (most significant bit) of the buffer.

Comment: I tried implementing this solution but found that the results weren't satisfactorily random. After generating thousands of numbers, I found that the vast majority of the numbers had 19 digits, the occasional number had 18 digits, and the very rare number had 17 digits. Out of the thousands of numbers I generated, I never saw any number with 16 digits or less. How could this solution be modified to fix this?

Comment: @kd7iwp: I fear you have a slightly befuddled perception of "random" here. The key here is the distribution of the generated values. Are the integers distributed uniformly? Yes, of course, since their bits are independent and uniform random variables. Now observe that there are ~10 times as many numbers with (n + 1) digits as there are with n digits, and it should be clear enough to you.

Comment: @Noldorin: How can we ignore MSB? Can you share?

Answer (score 29):

Use [`Random.NextBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextbytes.aspx) and [`BitConverter.ToInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint64.aspx) / [`BitConverter.ToUInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint64.aspx).

```
// Assume rng refers to an instance of System.Random
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
rng.NextBytes(bytes);
long int64 = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
ulong uint64 = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0);
```

Note that using [`Random.Next()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b3ta19y.aspx) twice, shifting one value and then ORing/adding doesn't work. `Random.Next()` only produces non-negative integers, i.e. it generates 31 bits, not 32, so the result of two calls only produces 62 random bits instead of the 64 bits required to cover the complete range of `Int64`/`UInt64`. ([Guffa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677373/generate-random-values-in-c/677602#677602) shows how to do it with *three* calls to `Random.Next()` though.)

Comment: Oh, good catch (comment) - I'm deleting mine, as the BitConverter etc is already well covered...

Comment: Okay - I put that in my answer rather than just a comment so that it would be more visible. I'm going to leave it in now anyway as a warning for the future (as otherwise it's an obvious alternative).

Comment: Due to the fact that majority of lcm PRNG are less random in the low order bits, generating 2 numbers and joining them together may introduce subtle biases...

Comment: @JonSkeet `Random` values are distributed uniformly. I'm not sure that we'll get uniformly disrtibuted value with following method, especially if we are dropping MSB. And we also can get a value from 2 randoms, if the second call will be `random.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue)` so all bytes will be filled.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: With which method? And where do you believe I'm dropping an MSB?

Comment: @JonSkeet standard `Random` generates positive-only numbers by default. See @Noldorin's comments

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: I'm still not sure what code you're referring to. Bear in mind that my code doesn't ask `Random` to produce full integers - just bytes. I'm then using `BitConverter` to convert those bytes. Both the `int64` and `uint64` variables in my answer could have *any* value within their respective ranges. Are you suggesting that `NextBytes` never populates the MSB of any array element? If so, that's just wrong.

Comment: @JonSkeet they are, but there is a big question if there are disributed correctly (according to central limit theorem)

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: To be honest, there's no question in my mind. We're taking a random sequence of bits, and converting them into integers in an obvious way. Every possible value has the same chance of occurring. I don't see any evidence that there's a problem here. If you think there is, I suggest you give a more concrete argument.

Comment: With those bytes we get a distribution `Z = X0 + X1*256 + X2*256*256 + ...` with independed random generated `X0`, `X1`... `X7`,  so in general case `Z` won't be a uniformly distributed variable. `Z` can be any value within the range, but not all values are equiprobable.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: Yes, they are. Every value is the result of exactly one 64-bit bit pattern, right? So are you suggesting that the bit patterns themselves aren't uniformly distributed? Which bit pattern do you think is more likely than any other bit pattern? Each bit within `bytes` is uniformly distributed, independently of the other bits... so every bit pattern is as likely as every other. If we were converting the values to `double`, that would be a different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet well, I agree. It will be exactly uniformly distributed. CLT is not applicable here because there is no intersections between bytes (it's obvious for us, but isn't for mathematics), so `Z = X0 + X1*256 + X2*256*256 + ...` is a bit incorrect here. Finally, we could generate a value with 4 (or 3 for positive-only) `rand.Next()` calls, by just specifying bottom bound `int.MaxValue`. It's better than 8 calls (because `Random.NextBytes` calls `InternalSample` for each byte)

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: That's changing your objection entirely, and is based on an implementation detail. You can do it with 3 calls to `Random.Next` even if you want the full range, given that each call generates 31 bits of random data and we only need 64 in total.

Answer (score 10):

Here you go, this uses the **crytpo services** *(not the `Random` class)*, which is (theoretically) a better RNG then the Random class.  You could easily make this an extension of Random or make your own Random class where the RNGCryptoServiceProvider is a class-level object.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
public static Int64 NextInt64()
{
   var bytes = new byte[sizeof(Int64)];    
   RNGCryptoServiceProvider Gen = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
   Gen.GetBytes(bytes);    
   return BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes , 0);        
}
```

Comment: This is definitely worthwhile noting, although judging by the question the OP doesn't seem to care too greatly about the randomness of the generated numbers. Also it's important to realise that RNGCryptoServiceProvider is *much* slower than Random (though performance may or may not matter here).

Answer (score 6):

You can use bit shift to put together a 64 bit random number from 31 bit random numbers, but you have to use three 31 bit numbers to get enough bits:

```
long r = rnd.Next();
r <<= 31;
r |= rnd.Next();
r <<= 31;
r |= rnd.Next();
```

Answer (score 5):

I always use this to get my random seed (error checking removed for brevity):

```
m_randomURL = "https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randnum?num=1&min=1&max=1000000000";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(m_randomURL);
StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
Random rand = new Random(Convert.ToInt32(stIn.ReadToEnd()));
```

random.org uses atmospheric noise to generate the randomness and is apparently used for lotteries and such.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say how you're going to use these random numbers...keep in mind that values returned by *Random* are not "cryptographically secure" and they shouldn't be used for things involving (big) secrets or (lots of) money.

Comment: -1 for not mentioning the .Net Crypto RNG. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx

Comment: Why is that relevant? Dan alludes to the fact that a PC can't generate a cryptographically secure random number. The RNGCryptoServiceProvider class doesn't fix that.

Comment: No, he said the Random class can't do it, he said nothing about computers not being able to.

Comment: And RNGCryptoServiceProvider generates cryptographically secure random numbers and satisfies that condition of his answer.

Comment: John Von Neumann: "Anyone who considers arithmetic methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin."

Comment: While he makes a good point, if he had just spent a minute more he would have found RNGCryptoServiceProvider and his answer would be much more valuable.

Comment: The asker did not mention he required a secure random number, but it is nice you pointed out that the Random class does not produce secure numbers, but you really should mention an alternative instead of leaving a dead end.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [`byte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx) array, fill it with random data and then convert it to [`long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) (`Int64`) or [ulong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx) (`UInt64`).

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(Int64)];
Random random = new Random();

random.NextBytes(buffer);
long signed = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);

random.NextBytes(buffer);
long unsigned = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer with `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` instead of `Random`. Here you can see how to remove the MSB so the result is always positive.

```
public static Int64 NextInt64()
{
    var buffer = new byte[8];
    new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(buffer);
    return BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0) & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of .NET 6, the `Random` class has a method for generating a random long.

```
var r = new Random();
long randomLong = r.NextInt64();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Random r=new Random();
int j=r.next(1,23);
Console.WriteLine(j);
```

Comment: the random class is used to randomly select the values.random class give a well environment to the user to do so