# How to generate int/long sequence identifier without using databases?

Tags: c#, generator, sequence

I want to generate sequence identifiers with the int/long type in C#, but I don't want to use the databases for storing the generated values, how can I do that? Would the CPU tick counter be helpful? Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Do you need this to be persistent?

Comment: Do you need a monotonically increasing counter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;


RegistryKey key = 
   Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey ("The Right Value");

private void InitializeTheKey()
{

    this.MaxIndex = 0; // Or any other value ..

}


public Int32 MaxIndex 
{ 
   get{ return  key.GetValue("MaxIndex"); }
   set{  key.SetValue ("MaxIndex", value); } 
}

public Int32 GetNewIndex()
{

    this.MaxIndex += 1;
    return this.MaxIndex;

}
```

> WARNING: DO NOT PLAY WITH THE
>   REGISTRY. If you do not know what you
>   are doing, you can cause any number of
>   costly problems. Use this code at your
>   own risk.

Comment: And it will reset when the application restarts.

Comment: I would save the MaxIndex in whatever file is going to store all those indexes.

Answer (score 0):

As long as Int32 is okay, just use rand:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int newID = rand.Next(0, Int32.MaxValue);
```

Or for Int64, someone has posted an extension method you could use here: [Generate random values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677373/generate-random-values-in-c)