# Why do i get a Overflow Exception when trying to run the same method with same parameters?

Tags: c#

Was thinking of creating a random number generator which will support `uint, long & ulong`. I got to making the random `uint` generator but got stuck on making a min, max generator.

This is what i have

```
public class Rand : System.Random

public uint UInt32(uint min, uint max)
{
    byte[] array = new byte[4];

    base.NextBytes(array);

    uint result = BitConverter.ToUInt32(array, 0);

    if (result < min | result > max)
    {
        UInt32(min, max); //here i get a StackOverflowException
    }
    return result;
}
```

Why do i get a `StackOverflowException` when trying to run the same method with the same parameters?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see what it's actually doing step by step, observing the variables?  You might answer your own question.

Comment: Basically you never return from the recursive function.

Comment: probably you're just stucked in a recursive function loop

Comment: rory.ap: No i havent tried that, will try it now.

Comment: if (result < min | result > max) is this correct or should be ||?

Comment: You generate random number and if it fails to match criteria (min-max range) - you call the same function again. But random number might fail to match this criteria arbitrary number of times, while stack size is not infinite, so often (how often depends on min and max) your recursive call eats up all the stack. That's not how you should generate random number in a range.

Comment: Since bit-patterns are 'predictable' i.e. you could try cutting out the bits that make you exceed your boundaries. To save yourself the looping/recursive calls. No idea how that might effect the "quality" of the generated numbers though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program's ability to exit from recursive invocations is dependent on the length of the interval [min..max]. The smaller the interval, the higher the probability of hitting `StackOverflowException`.

Since you are generating 4-byte integers, you have 2<sup>32</sup> possible values. Assuming uniform distribution of random values, the probability of hitting the interval between `min` and `max` is equal to (max-min)*2<sup>-32</sup>. The probability of continuing the recursive invocation is 1-(max-min)*2<sup>-32</sup>. If you want your recursive invocations to have a chance of ending within a reasonable number of calls, the interval between `min` and `max` should be pretty large in comparison to 2<sup>32</sup>.

You can avoid stack overflow at the expense of having a rather slow code by converting your recursive code to iterative (your recursive implementation is wrong, too, because it drops the result of recursive invocation, but it's not worth fixing anyway).

Comment: What makes the iterative approach (assuming you just mean a while loop) slower? Or do you mean its just slow generally rather than slower than a recursive version would be (if it didn't overflow)?

Comment: Everything's OK except your last sentence -- you can't (easily) implement `Random(min, max)` by delegating to `Random(int, int)`, let alone for `ulong`. For `ulong` in particular, not even `Sample` will do if you want a decent distribution, as that internally just scales an `int`. There are [other approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/677373/4137916), of course.

Comment: @Chris It does not make it slower, it makes it slow in absolute terms. Recursive code will be just as fast as the iterative one. In fact, it could be restructured for tail call optimization.

Comment: I will just do what @Lepijohnny once said in the comment section of the post, dunno why he removed it, and put a `& max` and the end of `BitConverter` its good enough.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you can do `Random(int, int)` and cast result to `(uint)` in unckecked context. Because int and uint have the same size - that will work fine (negative ints will result in big positive uints). For ulongs that's different story indeed.

Comment: @Evk: simply casting the input parameters will not give you correct results, taking range into account (my example of `0, uint.MaxValue` was obviously poorly chosen, as there it *will* work -- edited). You can do it, but not trivially.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Cool. I thought on rereading that was probably what you meant but thought I would check in case there was something I was missing. :)

Comment: @Demiz: using `&max` doesn't look like it will give you an even distribution which I would personally expect from a random number generator...

Comment: @Chris i get what you mean but idk what else to do. Its better than nothing.

Comment: @Demiz: How about work out the size of your range. Round up to the nearest power of 2. Generate a random number between 0 and your power of 2. Bitmask that. Discard those that are out of range (less than 50% chance to be out of range now). Add min value to your number (to bring it back into the actual range). There may well be better ways to do it but this should at least guarantee you uniformity with a relatively simple algorithm.